# PHP script that reads in Excel file to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foxpro

For my job we are undergoing a mass conversion of our `FoxPro` databases to `MySQL`. With the help of the answers of this post I was able to extract indexes and database structures from FoxPro tables to Excel files. I haven't been able to connect directly to a FoxPro table from PHP using either `odbc` or `dbase`.

I'm asking if it's possible to write a script that reads in the structure of the table and does a bit of massaging of the data to insert into MySQL programmatically. We can't have someone sitting for hours manually typing in each structure for the each table--there's just too many tables to convert. We need this process to be streamlined/automated.

I've read how to insert data from Excel files into MySQL but haven't seen any tutorials on inserting the table structure or the indexes from an Excel files.

Below is a snapshot of what the exported FoxPro table structure looks like. The script will need to convert to C to varchar and D to date time format and obviously create the table and it's structure.

[image]

We need to make this process specific to our section so that's why we haven't purchased any software to convert the data for us. There is also an issue with budgeting the money to purchase a converter.

Here's what I've tried to read the script into an array. I saved the excel file as a csv and pulled this down from the php.net site:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("struct.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The code gives me an output that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Sure, it's possible. You'll need to write a `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table - check [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). Judging from the image you posted, it looks like you have the column specifications, so it's just a matter of "translating" that for MySQL.

Comment: Correct, I'm looking to translate the excel data to MySQL.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anyone here who will write that code for you - it's likely to be a lengthy project. Not terribly difficult, but it will take some time. You should start working on it and ask specific questions here if you get stuck.

Comment: There are tools out there already to do this for you. Why reinvent the wheel?  For example a quick google search on `FoxPro to MySQL conversion` yielded this amongst first few results - http://dbconvert.com/convert-foxpro-to-mysql-pro.php

Comment: I agree Mike, reinventing the wheel isn't necessary. My job has been very clear though on not purchasing any tools. Dbconverter was the first thing I recommended but they didn't want to go that route. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Where do you got stuck? It seems not to be very difficult. You've got to do your `CREATE TABLE <tablename> (` once, for each line but the first is following a column specification, followed maybe by some indexes, closed by the closing bracket. Go on, you can do it!